# How do I pass a color image through a Pytorch convolutional layer with custom filter?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, rgb

I'm trying to visualize what happens when a *color* image passes through a convolutional layer. For that, I'm setting custom weights with zeroes and ones. **The problem I'm facing is that I'm losing the 3D channels, and get a 1D channel after passing the data through the layer.**

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

link = 'https://audimediacenter-a.akamaihd.net/system/production/media/85094/images' \
       '/2a4e98976b1f9088fe6ae883f2f29e4d8f3ed473/A1912967_x500.jpg?1575885688'

r = requests.get(link, timeout=10)
im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

pic = np.array(im)

horizontal_filter = torch.zeros(5, 5)
horizontal_filter[2, :] = 1

print(horizontal_filter)
```

This is my custom filter:

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Now I'm using the custom filter and repeat it to fit 3 channels.

```
hz = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
               out_channels=3,
               kernel_size=5,
               stride=1,
               bias=None)

hz.weight.data =  horizontal_filter.type('torch.FloatTensor').repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)

print(hz.weight.data.shape)
```

This is the shape of the filter:

```
torch.Size([1, 3, 5, 5])
```

I pass it through the convolutional filter and I'm losing the 3 channels:

```
zz = hz(torch.tensor(pic[None, ...]).permute(0, 3, 1, 2).type('torch.FloatTensor'))

print(np.transpose(zz.detach().numpy(), (0, 2, 3, 1)).shape)
```

```
(1, 329, 496, 1)
```

If I plot it, I don't have the colors anymore.

```
z = np.transpose(zz.detach().numpy(), (0, 2, 3, 1))[0, :, :, 0]

f, axarr = plt.subplots()
axarr.imshow(z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**tl;dr:** How do I pass a 3D picture through a convolutional layer and return an image with 3 channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not repeating the channels enough. Since you have 3 input and output channels, the Conv weight matrix would be `3x3x5x5`. Since you had set it to `1x3x5x5`, it was able to output only 1 channel.

You need to make the following change

```
hz.weight.data =  horizontal_filter.type('torch.FloatTensor').repeat(3, 3, 1, 1)
```

Because of your filter, your output would have a max value of ~3700. So to view, divide by the max using `z = z/np.max(z)` and then you get 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The number of output channels is equal to the number of filters, and the depth of each filter (number of kernels) should match the depth of the input image. 
As an example see the picture below (source: [cs231n](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)). There we have an input image of shape 7x7 with 3 channels and 2 filters W0 and W1 of shapes 3x3x3. The i-th input channel is convolved with the i-th kernel of the filter W0 (W1) and then they are summed giving the first (second) channel of the output.

In your example you have only one filter with three 5x5 kernels (1x3x5x5) and as result the output has one channel. To get output with 3 channels you would need three such filters, i.e. an array of shape (3x3x5x5).

[image]